# Delete Word Fields VBA does not work in Word 2013, worked in Word 2010

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a VBA macro which is run from Excel to import some information from a Word document. Before I start parsing I want to get rid of the Table of contents and other fields. The below code (stripped to a minimum) works in Office 2010 but not in Office 2013. I get a **"Method Delete in Object Field failed"** eror message but I don't understand why.

Thanks for any tips!

Bo

```
Sub ImportBOD()

    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim WordApp As Object

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    Dim fld As Word.Field


     wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", ,"Choose the Word document")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set wdDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(wdFileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    'Get rid of table of contents and other fields 
    For Each fld In wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.Fields
        fld.Delete
    Next


    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

Comment: when deleting you should go from last item in collection to first. See answer below + my comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Have to tried deleting them by index instead?

```
For i = 1 to wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.Fields.Count
    wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.Fields.Item(i).Delete
Next i
```

I have found sometimes that in loops removing the active object in this case `fld` is not always successful and VBA Error Messages are less than specific. Also it seems SEQ(Sequence Fields) and XE(IndexEntry Fields) cannot be `Unlink`ed which suggests to me that `Delete` may fail as well although Microsoft does not specify this is the case.

**Edit**

Based on comment looping last to first

```
For i = wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
    wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.Fields.Item(i).Delete
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately I'm getting the same error. I did, however, come up with a workaround: I used Unlink instead of Delete which is ok for my purpose. The reason I wanted to get rid of the fields was that I ran into problems when I tried to process the document by paragraphs, i.e. looping through the document paragraph by paragraph. The fields somehow disturbed the processing, but converting them to text with Unlink does the trick